# How do to do recursive async/await in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, recursion, async-await

I have the following code, stripped out of any specifics:

```
const installation = async() => {
  try {
    const call = await callToServer();
    
    if('finished' in call) {
      return call;
    } else {
      await callToServer();
    }
  } catch(e) {
  //
  }
}
```

And as you can see, I'd like to recursively call `callToServer` until I see `finished` inside its response. I understand why my code isn't working and why it's making only 2 calls (or 1, if it sees `finished` on the first run), but I don't know how to make it recursive.

I tried with a `for` loop and, well, it worked **as-is**, but in my case, I don't know the number of calls I need to make upfront. So I went to a `do...while` loop, since it seemed to fit:

```
do {
    const call = await callToServer();
} while(!('finished' in call));
```

But this only runs once. It sees that the `while(!...` doesn't actually know about `call`. How can I make it work?

Comment: Have a global call variable. So you would create const call outside the do-while loop.

Comment: _"And as you can see, I'd like to recursively call `callToServer`"_ - For recursion something has to call itself again. Nothing in your example does this. So something in `installation` would have to call `installation`

Comment: Note: `for` is a generic syntax for loops. You don't need to know how many times you need to lop to use `for`. For example you can do `for ( ; condition ; ) ...` which will behave exactly the same as `while (condition)`

Comment: @slebetman Huh, interesting. Let me see if I can find an "empty `for`" example or some documentation on that. I had always assumed that a `for` loop needs to know the number of steps it needs to run for initially. However, if `for ( ; condition ; )` is valid syntax, then it's just personal preference over `do...while`, right? It's just weird to have `for( i=0; !finished; i++)` for this use-case **for me.**

Comment: C programmers have been using `for (;;) ..` as infinite loop for a long time and it's supported in javascript as well. I've always thought `for (;;) ..` is a stupid way to do infinite loop because `#define ALWAYS 1; while (ALWAYS) ..` feels more readable to me. But yeah, `for` is very flexible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't necessarily need recursion, a simple loop will work to recall your `callToServer`.

You were on the right track with a `do...while` loop. You might consider putting a limit in on the number of calls before bombing out. The below will attempt 10 times before doing so - it uses a random chance on whether it works or not so you might see it bombing out.

```js
const installation = async() => {
  try {
    var call = null;
    var i = 0
    do {
       console.log("attempt",i++)
       call = await callToServer();
    } while(! ('finished' in call) && i <10 );
    return call;
  } catch(e) {
  //
  }
}

const callToServer = async() => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    if(Math.random()>0.95) {
      resolve({finished:true})
    }
    else {
      resolve({notfinished:true})
    }
  })
}

const test = async() => {
  var res = await installation()
  console.log(res)
}

test()
```

Comment: You are right! Someone else gave me this idea of not being stuck to just what's happening inside `do` and I ended up with a `finished` flag.

Answer (score 6):

```
} else {
  return await installation();
}
```

A recursive function would call the entire function again.

Comment: you're the only person here to actually address the missing `return`

Comment: Can confirm what @Mulan said - my recursive function kept diving out early until I added the return to my recursive function call.

Answer (score 0):

```
  const installation = async() => {
  try {
    const call = await callToServer();
    
    if('finished' in call) {
      return call;
    } else {
      return await installation();
    }
  } catch(e) {
  //
  }
}
```

Comment: This *can* work and if I could accept a sister answer, I'd accept it, but with this approach, I'm always calling `callToServer` with the same arguments. Assume I wanted to `callToServer` with arguments that come from `call`, I can't do that here and making it work this way would make it more complicated than it needs to be.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that using async/await is new syntax in ES that is similar to how generators `function*` and `yield` work, so we can do for, while, recursive call for async function in a sync syntax.

Here is an example that do recursive call while the target value is not met yet

```js
let counter = 0;
let res;


function delay(ms){
        return new Promise((res,rej) => setTimeout(res, ms));
}

async function callToServer(){
        await delay(100);
        return ++counter;
}







async function recursive(){

        res = await callToServer();
        console.log(`called server with return value = ${res}`);

        if(res < 10){
                return await recursive();
        }

        return 'RESULT';

}


(async function main(){
                
        let finalRes = await recursive();
        console.log(finalRes);

})()
```

this code will output:

```sh
called server with return value = 1
called server with return value = 2
called server with return value = 3
called server with return value = 4
called server with return value = 5
called server with return value = 6
called server with return value = 7
called server with return value = 8
called server with return value = 9
called server with return value = 10
RESULT
```

Comment: Yup, this works, but : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65490027/how-do-to-do-recursive-async-await-in-javascript/65490219#comment115783864_65490103 / so, while the answer is GOOD for this question specifically, https://stackoverflow.com/a/65490138/14906201 is more flexible while not trading too much readability away.